# Using rpy2 in jupyter notebook but there is no output. Error in withVisible({ : object 'returns' not found

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, rpy2, magic-command

[the screenshot for jupyternotebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Toj1p.png)

I've successfully installed ryp2 using wheel. I'm using Python 3.7.6 and rpy2 2.9.5.
I can get the output from jupter notebook when running python code but it doesn't work when using R magic. I tried to see if I can really use R by installing 'ggplot2' and it worked with installation bar poped out.

However, I cannot get any output when I use R magic.

Errors will come out like this. The error is so weird `Error in withVisible({ : object 'returns' not found`. `returns` is a python dataframe and was not converted to r object.
[Error in withVisible({](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxodo.png)

Other error like below. `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'p' not found`. Neither `p` nor `q` is initialized.
[Error in eval(predvars, data, env)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c6bF.png)

Anyone encountered the same problem?
Thank you very much in advance!

FYI:
[packages version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BqYQ.png)

Comment: Please copy-paste the text from screenshots into the body of your question. You are missing out on answers from users like me for whom reading from screenshots may be difficult.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! But I'm new to stack overflow and I don't have enough reputations to insert the image to the body.

Comment: No worries, no need to embed pictures (links are fine). It is just that in addition to having the picture, copy-pasting a reproducible example helps a lot for users with vision deficiency, screen readers and majority of users with healthy vision as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer; I do not know why you cannot see output of `1` for:

```
%%R
a = 1
a
```

but I know that the "errors" you see are there because the variables are indeed not defined - you still need to tell rpy2 to import (`-i` for input) or export (`-o` for output) variables between R and Python namespaces, this does not happen automatically (if it did you would end up with each object taking up twice as much space!). This is done using:

```
%R -i variable_to_import_from_python
```

And

```
%R -o variable_to_export_to_python
```

(or equivalently using `%%R`). It means that in your examples in order to Python `print(a)` you first need to:

```
%%R -o a
a = 1
a
```

And to have Python variable `b`, say `b = 1` in R you would need to:

```
%%R -i b
cat(b)
```

Please read the documentation for [using rpy2 in notebooks](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/generated_rst/notebooks.html) (magics are covered near the end) and the documentation of [RMagic](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/interactive.html?module-rpy2.ipython.rmagic#rmagic), as it is already explained in there.

I hope you will get an answer on the non-functioning R output soon. If you do not get one in the next few days please consider opening a bug report on rpy2 GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! May I know do you know why the error contains 'withVisible' ? I know as I didn't introduce my object to r but I don't know why the error contains `withVisible{`.

Comment: Because this is how rpy2 magic [evaluates your code](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/blob/74e753cef9df37903cfa771a60bcf8cf89cc9d1e/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py#L252-L282); you can safely ignore it. Maybe it will get prettier in future versions.